# ntpdate IPv4 query to localhost ntp server failing

Tags: ntp, hosts

the command `ntpdate -q -4 localhost` in an NTP server is making two queries to `127.0.0.1` and one of them fails:

is this failing because of the **/etc/hosts** file?

```
ntpdate -q -4 localhost
server 127.0.0.1, stratum 2, offset 0.000006, delay 0.02565
server 127.0.0.1, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
```

**/etc/hosts** file content:

```
::1             1a.ncomputers.org 1a localhost
127.0.0.1       1a.ncomputers.org 1a localhost
2a02:c207:2010:6775::1  1b.ncomputers.org 1b
2a02:c205:2009:8290::1  1c.ncomputers.org 1c
5.189.146.13    1b.ncomputers.org 1b
80.241.208.120  1c.ncomputers.org 1c
```

**/etc/ntpd.conf** file content:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
restrict default kod nomodify nopeer noquery notrap
restrict localhost
server 2001:4ca0:0:103::81bb:fe20
server 2001:638:a000:1123:123::1
server 2001:62a:4:311::123
```

**ntpdate** version: 4.2.8p10

Comment: Don't think you need to specify "-4" and I suspect a restriction is in place.  Can we see your ntp.conf file?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I am a little busy right now, so I will answer you using online content, so that it is easer, and then later answer you better. I am trying what you propose, but still not working, example [here](http://ncomputers.org/ntptest/20171003-232130-8474) ntp.conf in [chapter 2.3](http://ncomputers.org/ntp)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add this to your ntp.conf file to allow localhost IPV4 and IPV6 queries:

```
restrict 127.0.0.1 
restrict ::1
```